# quadratic function vs conic section

Tags: conic-sections, quadratics

I am categorizing types of math problems on the ACT. I started off with 'quadratic function' as one category, and 'conic sections' as another... It seemed like a simple classification at first, but then, I started thinking about it.....

What WOULD be the difference between a quadratic function and a conic section? Since a quadratic function is a parabola, and a parabola is a conic section...? Would it be like 'all poodles are dogs, but not all dogs are poodles'... or is does it depend on the context?

Answer (score 2):

We can imagine that all the conic sections can be divided into:-

(1) Pair of straight lines; (2) Ellipses; (3) Hyperbolas and (4) Parabolas.

However, the set of Parabolas can further be  subdivided into another subset whose axes of symmetries are only vertical. Quadratic function belongs to this category.

Added:-
[image]

Comment: Thanks! That helps me to place them in a schema that makes more sense.... BUT, now you've opened me to a new question (Math always does that, doesn't it!).... A pair of lines is considered a conic section??? I have never heard of that before! (I am a high school math tutor.)

Comment: @Jen The name conic section comes from cutting a cone at various angles into different sections. After the cutting, we are interested at studying the characteristics of the edges of the resultant cross-sections. If the cut is done at a correct angle, we will get a pair of intersecting lines. If one cone does not produce the shape of a pair of hyperbolas, try cutting 2 vertex-to-vertex connected cones.

Comment: Yes, I know that conic sections are all slices of a double-napped cone. I was questioning the designation of a pair of straight lines as a conic section, as I have never seen any mention of it before.mentioned in any of the links in the first couple of pages of a Google search of 'conic sections'.  Although, when I

Comment: {edit / continuation of above} .... So, now curious, I did a Google search of 'conic sections'. None of the links on the first two pages mention a pair of straight lines. So, I searched "pair of straight lines conic section", and I did find several hits, although it is notable that, aside from Q&A forums, the only places that straight lines are mentioned within the context of conic sections are test prep sites for engineering exams...

Comment: Also, you didn't mention circles, unless you are simply including them as a special case of an ellipse..... Anyway, I think that your first post answered my question. I'm going to leave the question open for a little while, though, to see if anyone else wants to chime in.

Comment: @Jen 1) Good point for considering circle as a special case of ellipse. I should have that mentioned too. 2) I have added in my post more than one instances of getting a pair of straight lines after cutting the cone into sections.

Comment: @Jen If you cut the cone's double nappe with a plane passing  *through the vertex* of cone  you get a pair of lines as a   *degenerate*  conic.